# Connecting to Teradata via SAS (SQL Explicit Passthrough), for data pull, is it recommended to use execute statement?

Tags: sql, sas, teradata

I have seen two options:

1. Not using execute statement

   ```
   libname lib "/dir";
   run;

   proc sql ; 
   CONNECT TO TeraData (Server = 'edw' User =&tduser pass=&tdpass Database = UDW Mode = TeraData);            
   create table lib.datanew as

   select * from connection to teradata 
   (select a.name,b.age from table1 a left join table2 b on a.pkey=b.pkey); disconnect from teradata; quit;
   ```
2. Using execute to create a multiset volatile table in Teradata and then bringing it to SAS library

   ```
   libname lib "/dir";
   run;

   proc sql;
   CONNECT TO TeraData (Server = 'edw' User =&tduser pass=&tdpass Database = UDW Mode = TeraData);
   execute(    create multiset volatile table datanew as

       (select a.name,b.age from table1 a left join table2 b on a.pkey=b.pkey)
           with data primary index (name) on commit preserve rows
       )
   BY TeraData;

   CREATE TABLE lib.datanew AS (SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO TeraData (SELECT * FROM datanew));
   disconnect from teradata;
   quit;
   ```

I just want to understand if one way or the other can be faster? If so, why?

Comment: There can be cases where using volatile tables helps "push down" more of the logic into the database, but that does not appear to be the case in this example. I would expect the first one to be very slightly better because it does a little less work. By the way, the second example seems to have a typo: it names the volatile table *datanew* but then tries to select from *libnew*; the names in the two requests need to match.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've corrected the table name typo.

Comment: Check with your Teradata DBA whether making the volatile table helps or hurts. The answer depends on how the tables are defined and how Teradata tries to optimize the query.  For example it might save time to do in one step if it means that Teradata can figure out more easily how to avoid having to access all of the data or prevent skewing of the query so that one or more nodes become a bottle neck to performance.

Answer (score 1):

So, when you use `execute` statement, you use pass through facility ([Docs](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=spdsug&docsetTarget=n095mdd1wof6ogn1neyglan77ghc.htm&docsetVersion=5.4&locale=en)). 
That mean that your sql code will be executed right in DBMS, and sas will only get the result table.

More examples you can see in [pdf](https://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug93/NESUG93061.pdf)

Also [SAS Community](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/libname-vs-pass-through/td-p/143794) has a discussion .

Comment: Hi Sanek, thanks for your question edit and answer. However, both the options I listed are using explicit passthrough (I'm not using libname to connect to Teradata). So I guess there is some other difference.

Comment: @DSR , Can you execute both codes with strace? code: `options sastrace=',,t,d' sastraceloc=saslog nostsuffix;` from [here](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/081-2013.pdf) . So, I expect , that you will see difference queries.

Answer (score 0):

Answering part of my question.

What I found is that when I need to create multiple volatile tables within Teradata, using the already created ones, 2) is the normal choice; I can run the proc sql commands, as if, I were in the Teradata SQL assistant environment.